# Error when trying to deploy SAP HANA developer edition on Azure

Tags: azure, hana

I am trying to make an instance of SAP HANA, developer edition 1.0 Rev 80 in SAP CAL.

When the instance is processing I receive the following error:

> Operation Start failed on step CreateDeploymentAction with message:
> BadRequest:The subscription policy limit for resource type 'cores
> count' was exceeded. The limit for resource type 'cores count' is 2
> per subscription, the current count is 0, and the requested increment
> is 8.

Now I am following this guide: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/22/step-by-step-guide-for-deployment-of-sap-hana-developer-edition-on-microsoft-azure/
and it is at figure 19 where it happens.

I already tried contacting SAP Support but they couldn't help me any further so I hope someone here can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP Hana requires 8 cores, 56 GB memory for it to create an instance on Azure, the error message that you have indicates that your azure acccount does not have the specific number of cores to create the instance.

You can go through this document http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-28294 for a thorough explanation on creating your sap hana instance on azure i.e after you free up the cores.